# What is ShellId? Why would I require it?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell has a built in variable named `$ShellId`. It's mentioned in the [`#Requires` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires), and it's a property on [`RunspaceConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspaceconfiguration.shellid(v=vs.85).aspx). But I can't find any documentation about what it's supposed to do. The fact I can specify it in a `#Requires` statement suggests it has some intended purpose, but I can't find what.

What is the purpose of `$ShellId`? In what situations would I make it a dependency for my script?

Comment: See [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/persistent-powershell-the-powershell-profile/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would like you to understand the difference between [The Shell and The Host](https://powershell.org/2013/10/19/the-shell-vs-the-host/).

Whatever we are running in ISE or PSConsole, they are all Host.

`#Requires –ShellId Microsoft.PowerShell` ---
This uses the default PowerShell Shell.

when you test ***$shellid***, the console and ISE both return Microsoft.PowerShell .

You can specify local shell like:

```
#requires –ShellId MyLocalShell
```

If it is an independent shell irrespective of the console and which inturns uses powershell engine at the backend, then we need that shellId basically. Mostly during Runspaces.

***$shellId*** contains the identifier of the current shell.